# SQLite3 getting output from one table as input to another

Tags: sqlite, sql

Table1 has the following columns

problem
t1
t2

t1 and t2 are INT

problem is the result of the values from t1,t2

t1 can be 1,2,3,4,5
t2 can be 6,7,8,9,10

I could write an SQL query that says

SELECT * from Table1 WHERE (t1=1 OR t1=2 OR t1=3 OR t1=4 OR t1=5) AND (t2=6 OR t2=7 OR t2=8 OR t2=9 OR t2=10)

But instead of writing out the entire expression (shown above), I want to store it into another table (called Table2)

Table2 has the following columns
data_entered
data_results

data_entered is 1
data_results is a string with the following data "(t1=1 OR t1=2 OR t1=3 OR t1=4 OR t1=5)"

data_entered is 2
data_results is a string with the following data "(t2=6 OR t2=7 OR t2=8 OR t2=9 OR t2=10)"

so I want to create a QUERY where I could say

SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ... (and specify data_entered) the results should be the same as the above mentioned SQL.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first query, you can use IN instead:

```
select * from table1 where t1 in (1,2,3,4,5) and t2 in (6,7,8,9,10);
```

Then instead of storing sql code in table2, store each value in a seperate row.

```
create table data (entered, result);
insert into data values (1, 1);
insert into data values (1, 2);
...
insert into data values (2, 10);
```

Then you can do:

```
select *
  from table1
 where t1 in (select result from data where entered = 1)
   and t2 in (select result from data where entered = 2);
```